# jQuery / javascript - Pular input quando atingir o maxlength

Tags: javascript, jquery

Bom dia amigos!

Seguinte, quero fazer uma função que se atingir a maxlength da input (no caso 2 caracteres), ele pula para a próxima input. Fiz o código abaixo que não está rodando...

```js
var inputZin = $('.idade-viajantes only-number');
var jumpInput = function() {
  if(inputZin.value.length == 2) {
    $(this).parents(input).next.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="idade-viajantes only-number" name="idade" maxlength="2" type="text" onkeyup="jumpInput()"/>
            <input class="idade-viajantes only-number" name="idade" maxlength="2" type="text" onkeyup="jumpInput()"/>
            <input class="idade-viajantes only-number" name="idade" maxlength="2" type="text" onkeyup="jumpInput()"/>
            <input class="idade-viajantes only-number" name="idade" maxlength="2" type="text" onkeyup="jumpInput()"/>
            <input class="idade-viajantes only-number" name="idade" maxlength="2" type="text"/>
            
         <script src="jquery.js"></script>
```

Anteriormente, eu havia feito uma lógica em javascript puro, porém utilizava id's em cada input... então tentei fazer usando jQuery para usar o "parents" e "next" só que não está rolando.

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tente

```js
$(".idade-viajantes").keyup(function() {
  if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
    $(this).next('.idade-viajantes').focus();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="idade-viajantes only-number" name="idade" maxlength="2" type="text" />
<input class="idade-viajantes only-number" name="idade" maxlength="2" type="text" />
<input class="idade-viajantes only-number" name="idade" maxlength="2" type="text" />
<input class="idade-viajantes only-number" name="idade" maxlength="2" type="text" />
<input class="idade-viajantes only-number" name="idade" maxlength="2" type="text" />
```

Comment: putz show de bola, invés de eu chamar a função em cada elemento no html, chama apenas uma única vez... fora a minha sintaxe tava meio torta também... brigadão pela força mano